# Controller Routing with Parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

got a little n00b problem with Laravel 4. I have following routes:

```
Route::get('search', 'MovieController@search');
Route::get('edit/{$id}', 'MovieController@edit');
Route::get('/', 'MovieController@index');
```

and the following controller:

```
class MovieController extends BaseController {

protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

public function index()
{
    $movies = Movie::paginate(30);
    return View::make('index')->with('movies', $movies);
}

public function search()
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['sq'])) {
        Cache::forever('sq', $_REQUEST['sq']);
    }
    $movies = Movie::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.Cache::get('sq').'%')->paginate(30);

    return View::make('index')->with('movies', $movies);
}

public function edit($id) {
    return View::make('edit')->with('id', $id);
    }

}
```

Now a call like this won't work:

```
<a href="edit/{{ $movie->movie_id }}">
```

I get a "NotFoundHttpException". The URL seems right: laravel/public/edit/2 e.g.

If i remove all the $id stuff from the code, so I route only to edit, it works.

Hopefully I could express myself enough, so somebody can help me. It's driving me nuts.

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your routes.php, it's not `Route::get('edit/{$id} ...` but `Route::get('edit/{id}`

Comment: @AlexKevler is not a n00b, yeah !